# strange perl issue with logical operators

Tags: perl

Am doing this on mac, perl version is

```
This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level

$ perl -e "$t=false;while(!($t)){print 1}"
$ perl -e "$t=true;while(!($t)){print 1}"
$ perl -e "$t=true;while(not($t)){print 1}"
$ perl -e "$t=false;while(not($t)){print 1}"
$
```

Why would this result? Anything I have missed?

Comment: What is the result you're getting and what were you expecting? It's worth noting that `true` and `false` are not Perl keywords. `1` and `0` are commonly used. Also your code should almost certainly be in single rather than double quotes - the shell will try to replace `$t` before running your code. The Bash shell will also be confused by the `!` in a double-quoted string.

Comment: When asking a question like this, it's usually helpful to explain what you think is strange in the output. Any Perl programmer looking at your examples would think the behaviour is completely expected. If you tell us what you find unexpected then we can debug your misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood):

> **Truth and Falsehood**
>
> The number 0, the strings '0' and "" , the empty list `()`, and `undef` are all false in a boolean context. All other values are true. Negation of a true value by `!` or `not` returns a special false value.

`$t=false` sets `$t` to the string `false` when `strict 'subs'` is disabled. The string `false` is truthy when used in a boolean context.

Therefore:

```
$t=false # truthy
!$t      # falsy
$t=true  # truthy
!$t      # falsy
```

Perl doesn't have special keywords for true and false; it's common to use 1 for true and 0 for false.